# Docker container build fails on local if a unit test fails but build successfully on Azure

Tags: python, django, docker

init.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /code
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py load_fixtures
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py test || exit 1
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

When the test fails my docker compose fails and container is not built but when I take the code online to azure pipeline. It works with out giving test error.

Comment: What's the test doing that it fails?  When you run the test suite in your development setup, outside a container in a virtual environment, does it pass, and do you need to repeat it every time you start the server?  Can you include any details of your test code or the broader environment or the actual error message?

Comment: The tests are python Unit test to check if the code works fine. When I compose my docker container on my docker desktop , the container builds up but stops since one of the test in there fails.( Failing the test on purpose to see if the container stops building or not)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to verify the exit code on the test

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /code
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py load_fixtures
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py test && echo $? &&
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: This is the error I get in my docker desktop : `First differing element 0:

307.0

308


- [307.0, 307.0, 157.0]

?    ^^^     --     --


+ [308, 307, 157]

?    ^



----------------------------------------------------------------------

Ran 3 tests in 0.162s


FAILED (failures=1)

Destroying test database for alias 'default'..`